# Best strucure for Authentication / Authorisation having different Database for Security

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, form-authentication

I am a bit of newbie when it comes to security concepts. The mechanism I have used for Authentication and Authorization so far is always custom database login using custom roles and permission checked against URL with in website Filter Context method.

We are now building new framework where our new application requires very secure authentication and authorization implementation. We are having 2 databases for our application, one is application database and other is security database. Security database contains all user details with their roles and permissions.

We will have one Website, and few set of Web APIs in which we need same level of authentication/authorization implemented. I have read about Forms Authentication and OAuth, but honestly I am totally out of clue which would suit best in our our scenario and what should be the structure for Authentication/Authorization framework for those two.

Please note, we do not require any third party account authentication like Facebook / Google account.

I have couple of random thoughts about it. However, I am happy to try    other ways anyone would like to suggest.

1. Should I create separate WEB API just for authentication /
   authorization and both Website and Web API will call that API before
   acting on incoming request?
2. Should I use it the way, I was doing before? Using 2 connection
   strings in DB and authenticate / authorize user in filter context method
   manually for each request on both Web API and Website separately.
3. Implement custom Forms-Authentication for both Websites and Web API
   where common security library project references on both ?
4. Implement using OAuth? How should I structure it and what will be
   the best way for storing token?

As I mentioned earlier, I am a bit newbie on this and haven't got any clue. So forgive me if some of my comments are silly.

I would appreciate any ideas / help on this.

Thanks

Meghana

Comment: Have you got an answer for the best architecture for authentication and authorization ? If yes , pls share with us.

Comment: @AswinArshad, I haven't got any answer for this. But I am going to try implementing Identity Server as a Authorization Server for both Web application and Web API. Which will be our centerlized authentication and authrorisation server.